# How to add more into LocalStorage instead of overwriting it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am making a blog and I want to store more into the local storage instead of only one. How do I do it?

```
function saveToLocalStorage(){
    var title = document.getElementById("title1");
    var titlesaved=title.innerHTML;
    var para = document.getElementById("p1");
    var parasaved = para.innerHTML;

    localStorage.setItem("Title",titlesaved);
    localStorage.setItem("Paragraph",parasaved);    
}

function RetrieveData(){
    document.getElementById("title2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Title");
    document.getElementById("paragraph2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Paragraph");
}
```

Comment: Store it using a different key. If you want to store using the same key, store a list of values with each key instead.

Comment: What do you mean by storing it using a different key?

Comment: You're using the keys "Title" and "Paragraph" to store the data. You could just use a different string as a key. I'd probably go with Justinas' solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your data as JSON:

```
var data = [{Title: '', Paragraph: ''}];
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Than when you need to update/add information, just take that JSON, parse it, edit and put back:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
data.push({Title: 'a', Paragraph: ''});
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: So do i retain my previous code or do i change the whole thing to that?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use JSON

for the HTML

```
<input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
<button id="button">Kayıt Ol</button>
```

for the JS

```
let number = 0;
let button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener ("click", function(){
   number++;
});
$("#button").click(function (e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   let user = $("#user").val();
   let password = $("#password").val();

   localStorage.setItem("Username" + number,user);
   localStorage.setItem("Password" + number,password);
});
```

Comment: And how would you retrieve it? Try Username1, Username2, ..., UsernameN until one does not give a result?

Comment: will be like a db. Username1 for example first user. when u want the get the first user localStorage.getItem("Username1","Password1"); u will take the result.

Result will be "n" how many input will be in your site will be Username"n" + Password"n"